# Get Reference of multiple Elements

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend

I have this a bunch of input fields which are created dynamically

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let rowIdx = index">
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let colIdx = index">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input #inputs #test type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                    (keyup.enter)="shiftFocusEnter(rowIdx, colIdx)">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
                    {{ option }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to get access to these input fields in my classes. 
I'm currently using

```
@ViewChild('test', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) test: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

to access it.
However this will only give me the first input field of all the ones which have been created through the loop.

Using ViewChildren instead only results in Errors while calling intern functions of the "test" object

e.g.

**this.test.closePanel()** => *"this.test.closePanel is not a function"*

**Edit1:**

To provide more info, I have a dynamically created table (rows and columns).
My table is currently filled with multiple input fields. I can tab through these input fields by pressing the enter key.

However if i tab by pressing the enter key, the suggestion panel of the angular autocomplete material will not close. Thats why I try to call the closePanel() method manually however by using this approach described above, only the first cell is "recognized" hence the closePanel() method only works on the first cell - input element

**EDIT 2:**

I managed to solve this a couple of weeks ago but forgot to update in case someone has this problem as well.

This is how my method looks like right now:

```
    shiftFocusEnter(rowIdx: number, colIdx: number) {
    console.log("Enter", rowIdx, colIdx);  
    if(colIdx == 4 && rowIdx == 5) {
    console.log("Reached end of row");
    }
    else {
      colIdx = colIdx + this.columns.findIndex(c => c.editable);
      this.focusInput(rowIdx, colIdx);
      this.autocompletes.toArray().forEach(el => {
        el.closePanel();
      })
    }
  }

  focusInput(rowIdx: number, colIdx: number) {
    console.log("FOCUS ON", rowIdx, colIdx);
      let inputEls = this.inputs.toArray();
      let flatIdx = (rowIdx * this.columns.length) + colIdx;
      inputEls[flatIdx].nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Comment: Where are you putting your `ViewChildren` reference ? It should be next to your `*ngFor`

Comment: Its in the input field. I have 2 references there.
`<input #inputs #test type="text"`
I dont know if its even correct to put two references in one input tag.
Putting the `#test` reference into `*ngFo` gives me an Error: 

**Cannot read property 'closePanel' of undefined**

I'll edit the first post to provide more info

Comment: Use @ViewChildren with the *ngFor, not the autocomplete !

Comment: I've added a reference **demo** to the `<tr>` tag which contains an *ngFor loop and accessed it with `@ViewChildren('demo', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) demo: MatAutocompleteTrigger;`

However this will give the same error as above. Did you perhaps mean something else?

I'll try to wrap the `mat-form-field` for the entire body and not for the input fields only...

Comment: Well then, remove the local variables, and use this instead : `@ViewChildren(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autocompletes: QueryList<MatAutocompleteTrigger>` (or whatever type thos autocomplete are)

Comment: This should give you the whole list of all of your autocompletes on your page.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I now have a list of all inputs. Do you perhaps have an idea on how to get the current input the user is on?

Comment: No sorry, I have no idea ... I usually name them one by one, I never faced this issue :/

Comment: Hi again, what exatly is the `@ViewChildren(MatAutoCompleteTrigger)` part looking at. 
What I need is to give **autocompletes** querylist another parameter called rowIdx and colIdx which have been created inside the `tr` and `td` tag for each element inside that list.
I have to do that in order to access specific elements inside that list or do you have an idea on how to get an element inside that list?

Comment: @ViewChildren works as a charm. I use it with dynamic generating autocompletes. Make sure that the mdinput has an unique id.